# ¿Podrían ayudarme con este error? (JAVA Netbeans)

Tags: java, netbeans, nodos, árboles

tengo un problema de nullPointerException.

[image: Aquí tengo una subrutina que me llena un árbol mediante la lectura de un archivo]

Inicie por colocar un caso base donde mi raiz, de la clase Nodo sea igual a null, que es como se encuentra al principio. En teoría, al confirmar que la raiz está vacía, debería generarse un nuevo nodo con la primera línea del archivo .txt.

[image: Aquí inicializo la raiz root de la clase Nodo]

Sin embargo, al tratar de utilizar esa raíz, que supuestamente ahora debería tener la información de la primera línea del archivo, el programa me reclama un nullPointerException, es decir no me está llenando la variable global y no lo entiendo muy bien.

[image: Aquí utilizo la variable root de la clase Nodo, para colocar su información en un label]

Me marca el nullPointerException al tratar de usar root en mi código después.

¿Podrían ayudarme a saber por qué no se está metiendo la información de br.readLine() en root?

Gracias.

Código en texto:

```
 public void readTree(Nodo raiz, BufferedReader br) throws IOException {
        String info;
        if ((info = br.readLine()) != null) {
            nuevo = false;
            if (raiz == null) {
                raiz = new Nodo(info);
            }
        }
 }
```

Luego en el constructor lo utilizo como

```
readTree(root, br);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tu código como texto por favor

Comment: public void readTree(Nodo raiz, BufferedReader br) throws IOException {
        String info;
        if ((info = br.readLine()) != null) {
            nuevo = false;
            if (raiz == null) {
                raiz = new Nodo(info);
            }
        }
    }

Comment: edita tu pregunta y ahi agrega por favor

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cuál es la solución a todos los errores NullPointerException presentes, pasados y futuros?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42977/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-soluci%c3%b3n-a-todos-los-errores-nullpointerexception-presentes-pasados)